# Using SQL Server Service Broker in Powershell script?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, service-broker

I have a PowerShell script do the following tasks:

```
Loop a big database table
  Generate text file
  Zip the text file
  FTP upload the zipped file
  Write to the log table
```

The step generating text file may take short or longer time depends on the data. And the FTP uploading time takes a while. So I want to make at least these two steps asynchronous. Is SQL Server Service Broker a viable choice? Is there any example? Any other options?

Answer (score 0):

You cant make them aysnc in PowerShell, but you could use the Start-Job cmdlet to put them on another thread and wait until they complete.

Answer (score 0):

Using Service Broker will will by default make them work asynchronously. The tricky thing would be if you still want to run some of then sequentially, for which you need to add a conversation-group id for them.